# SoundCloud 503 - Service Unavailable

Tags: java, soundcloud

When I have request to SoundCloud API sometimes I have "Error 503 - Service Unavailable". What is it and how it repair?

Answer (score 4):

A HTTP 503 signals that the webserver is overloaded or in maintenance. This also means you cannot fix the underlying problem. (other than maybe try to perform less requests if possible)

Comment: ... Or catch the exception, sleep for a number of seconds and try again.

Comment: @carlspring: "sleep for a number of seconds and try again" the implication of the HTTP standard is that you should do that only if there is a `Retry-After` header telling you when it would be worthwhile trying again.